# Product-scoped custom dimensions in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is it currently possible to add custom dimensions at the product level in GA4, so that they can be used for reporting?

For instance if I send data that looks like this:

```
event: 'purchase',
value: 500,
items: [
{
  item_id: 12345,
  item_name: "New Book",
  item_author: "John Smith"
}
]
```

Is there any way to configure GA4 so that I can see the item_author field in product reports? I've seen as late as October 2021 that there is no support for this, but wondered if this had changed, or if Google had published any info as to whether this WILL happen and if so WHEN it will happen?

Comment: You may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ this question does not appear to be programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible. GA4 is still inferior to GA UA in many ways. Product scope dimensions are on the roadmap.

There are a few workarounds we're using like using product categories to store product dimensions. Read this for more: [Can I add custom parameters to 'items' in GA4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576370/can-i-add-custom-parameters-to-items-in-ga4/69577191#69577191)

//to moderators: please keep this story even if it looks like a duplicate. It gives a good and searchable title to a popular question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have Google said anything about this explicitly? Is it certain that such functionality will eventually be implemented?

Comment: Simo Ahava claimed it. Not sure if it has been officially confirmed.

Comment: google's tooltip when creating a custom dimension or metrics in GA4 seems to be official confirmation of this: `Session and item scoped custom dimensions are on the product roadmap.`